# What private data can apps access without any specified permissions?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, security

Let's say an app doesn't require any permissions at all. What could that app access that could be a potential privacy risk? Other app usage? List of installed apps? Check is my screen unlocked? Google Analytics?

Comment: Nothing prevents a seemingly an innocent app to exploit a privilege-escalation vulnerability to take control of your precious and private data. Learn about QuadRoot to know more. https://blog.checkpoint.com/2016/08/07/quadrooter/ // Related question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208508/96277

Comment: Closely related: [Are multiple-users protected from each other differently than apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207725/218526).

Answer (score 2):

- Permissions change with practically with every Android version , so without specifying the Android version, it is difficult to answer. Notwithstanding that, for a [primer on permissions](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms) and to see how how crazy, it actually is, see [The Android authorization model: a perfidious construct](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&nv=1&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://www.kuketz-blog.de/das-android-berechtigungsmodell-ein-perfides-konstrukt/&xid=17259,1500004,15700023,15700186,15700191,15700248,15700253&usg=ALkJrhjqFIICD0tQa1-Ovd_2SN3ZlZPqNA)

Sourced from Izzy's blog (thanks)

*Permissions *do not* define what all an app can access, which is covered in [Irfan's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/131553). Also see [Izzy's primer on permissions](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=perms)

- App description of [XPrivacy Lua](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/eu.faircode.xlua/), which is an Xposed module, to protect privacy. Information below can be accessed *without* permissions (readers are welcome to add)

> - Use analytics (Fabric/Crashlytics, Facebook
>     app events, Firebase Analytics, Google Analytic, Mixpanel, Segment)
> - Usetracking ( user agent for WebView only, Build properties,
>     network/SIM country/operator)